# Stop valitron validation of chained rules at first fail

Tags: php, validation

I have set up a validation rules chain in valitron, the last of which is a custom rule.

```
$this->validator->rule('required', ['id'])->rule('integer', ['id'])->rule(function($field, $value, $params, $fields) use ($input) {
        // My custom code here
    }, ['id'])->message("Not a valid Launcher ID");
```

Problem is: I prefer to NOT execute my custom validation if id is empty or not a number. In other words: I want to stop the evaluation at the first fail of the chain.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
    /**
     * Should the validation stop a rule is failed
     * @param bool $stop
     */
    public function stopOnFirstFail($stop = true)
    {
        $this->stop_on_first_fail = (bool)$stop;
    }
```

https://github.com/vlucas/valitron/blob/master/src/Valitron/Validator.php#L1242

Simply call `$this->validator->stopOnFirstFail()` prior to validating.

Comment: Thank you! However, not quite what I was looking for. I was not clear, sorry. I want to stop after the first fail on a specific chain. Using your method, it stops at any other fail rule, even on other parameters.

Comment: @Lorenzo Looking at the source code, Valitron does not have any built-in option for rule chains. Your example doesn't actually add the rules as a chain, it just adds them individually one after another. To get the behaviour you want, you'd have to write it yourself. Possibly by nesting a second validator inside a rule in the 'parent' validator.